# keep content inside a Card from flowing outside of it

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using the grid system to layout out three filters and a button.  The button is partially outside the card.  I want it to break to a new row if it can't fit.

I've tried playing with the col-lg- and col-auto, but can't seem to get that right combination.

[image]

```
<div class="row g-1">
        <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
            <div class="card shadow">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3>Activity</h3>
                    <div class="row g-1 align-items-end">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Location</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ctLocation" runat="server" CssClass="form-select"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ctStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label">End Date</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ctEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 mb-3">
                            <input type="button" id="ctRefresh" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Refresh" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="mt-3">
                        <canvas id="dailyTraffic" height="100"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution: add `col-auto` to the last column (i.e., the one which contains the button).**

The class `col-auto` will push the button to a new line if there's not enough space for it.

[image: Not enough space]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row g-1">
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
    <div class="card shadow">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Activity</h3>
        <div class="row g-1 align-items-end">
          <div class="col-lg-5 mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Location</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ctLocation" runat="server" CssClass="form-select"></asp:DropDownList>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ctStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">End Date</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ctEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <input type="button" id="ctRefresh" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Refresh" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="mt-3">
          <canvas id="dailyTraffic" height="100"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let's say you change "Location" column from `col-lg-5` to `col-lg-3`. Now there's enough space for the button to be in the same line.

[image: Enough space]

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row g-1">
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
    <div class="card shadow">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Activity</h3>
        <div class="row g-1 align-items-end">
          <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Location</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ctLocation" runat="server" CssClass="form-select"></asp:DropDownList>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ctStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">End Date</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ctEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datepicker"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <input type="button" id="ctRefresh" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Refresh" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="mt-3">
          <canvas id="dailyTraffic" height="100"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```